# Issue with "Get" message with gmail api v1 (Net)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, google-api-dotnet-client, gmail-api

Im trying to get info of a gmail message in a datagridview but only returns the datagridview empty (even when I erase the "return nothing" line) but when I try in apis-explorer I get the 200 ok response. What am I doing wrong?

The code Im using is from the google developers documentation:

```
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Tasks.v1
Imports Google.Apis.Tasks.v1.Data.Tasks
Imports Google.Apis.Tasks.v1.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data

Public Class Form1
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Dim scope = New List(Of String)
    Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Secrets.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID"
        Secrets.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    End Sub

  Public Shared Function GetMessage(service As GmailService, userId As [String], messageId As [String]) As Message
        Try
            Return service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        'Return Nothing
    End Function
    Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
        Dim userId As String = "GMAIL ACCOUNT"
        Dim messageId As String = "MESSAGE ID"
        Try
            scope.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom)
            Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scope, "XXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.google.com", CancellationToken.None).Result()
            initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
            initializer.ApplicationName = "APP NAME"
            Dim service = New GmailService(initializer)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = GetMessage(service, userId, messageId)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you able to get any calls to work?  Say something trivial like labels.list()?  I presume it's not throwing an Exception?  If that's the case, can you please print out and include the entire response received (HTTP headers and body)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Eric but I already solved making some changes. I hope this helps other people because the google developers documentation its not too clear

```
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data

Public Class Form1
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Dim scope = New List(Of String)
    Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Secrets.ClientId = "CLIENT ID"
        Secrets.ClientSecret = "CLIENT SECRET"
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function GetMessage(service As GmailService, userId As [String], messageId As [String]) As Message
        Try
            Return service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
        Try
            scope.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom)
            Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scope, "XXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.google.com", CancellationToken.None).Result()
            initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
            initializer.ApplicationName = "APP NAME"
            Dim service = New GmailService(initializer)
            Dim userId As String = "EMAIL"
            Dim messageId As String = "MESSAGE ID"

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = GetMessage(service, userId, messageId).Payload.Headers
            TextBox1.Text = (GetMessage(service, userId, messageId).Snippet)        
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Rather than posting an entire new code segment can you just summarize what was the bug originally?

Comment: Sorry, Im new with apis. I dont know what was the bug originally, I just put the "dim userId" and "dim messageId" in another place and then the code work perfectly.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with .NET but moving the variable declaration "dim ..." from outside the try block to inside it seems very unlikely to have changed anything here--i think that was a red herring and your issue is elsewhere.